# How to removing annoying auto selection in VS Code

Tags: go, flutter, visual-studio-code, ide

[image: Error]

VS Code automatically selects somethings sometimes not only strings inside quotes but also language keywords sometimes. It usually after automatically closing parentheses or after an IntelliSense auto-completion.

This is very much annoying because it prevents further autocompletion when the text gets selected automatically autocomplete dont work.How can I solve this

Comment: Have you checked your VS Code settings?

Comment: Yes I have didn't find anything of that sort